# could not invoke RNfusedlocation.getCurrentPosition - react-native-geolocation-service

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

react-native-geolocation-service(^5.3.1) throws this error or app crashed when Geolocation.getCurrentPosition() is called. The error started getting after I have added react-native-maps(^1.8.0) library. It was working fine before. After doing a lot of search, i saw somewhere it was probably due to version mismatch of playservices from other modules.

react-native version - 0.72.3

In my android/build.gradle >
`googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.0.0"`

When i change `googlePlayServicesVersion` version then the build fails with the following message:
`* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-device-info:compileDebugAidl'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-device-info:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:18.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :react-native-device-info

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-device-info:compileDebugAidl'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-device-info:debugCompileClasspath'. > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:18.0.0. Required by: project :react-native-device-info`

Tried -
bumping googlePlayServicesVersion to 17.+/18.0.0/20.0.0.

`implementation (project(path: ':react-native-device-info')) { exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services' }`
added the above line in android>app>build.gradle

Comment: did you fix this? tried answers but still getting the same error...

Answer (score 29):

Faced similar issue, after hours of debugging here is the solution below.

In android/build.gradle:

Add this line =>`playServicesLocationVersion = "21.0.1"`  inside buildscript.ext

In android/app/build.gradle:

Add this line or upgrade the version to 21.0.1 if older version already exists=>

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1' **inside dependencies**
```

Comment: Is the second part necessary?

Comment: It worked for me by adding the second part.

Answer (score 8):

Try this =>

In android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    //..
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "21.0.1" //add this line
}
}
```

In android/app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
//..
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1' // add this line

//..
```

}

Comment: did this exactly, it works.

Answer (score -1):

playServicesLocationVersion = "21.0.1" add this Line project/build.gradle
not android/build.gradlew