# could not invoke RNFusedLocation.getCurrentPosition null in react native

Tags: react-native, null, geolocation, location

I only got this error and other people can run in their laptop for this project

[image]

why does I only face this issue?

We all are together cloning from git this project

Comment: make sure your emulator has the google play services, if not create another emulator with google play

Comment: Does this answer your question? [could not invoke RNfusedlocation.getCurrentPosition - react-native-geolocation-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274148/could-not-invoke-rnfusedlocation-getcurrentposition-react-native-geolocation-s)

Answer (score 0):

add this line googlePlayServicesVersion = "21.0.1" in

```
buildscript {
    ext {googlePlayServicesVersion = "21.0.1"}
android/build.gradle
```

after, cd android ./gradlew clean or gradlew clean

Answer (score 0):

Add this line =>playServicesLocationVersion = "21.0.1" inside buildscript.ext

In android/app/build.gradle:

Add this line or upgrade the version to 21.0.1 if older version already exists=>

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1' **inside dependencies**